# Encabezado y contenido de reporte se empalman PDF -itextsharp

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, itextsharp

Buen dia compañeros, estoy creando un reporte para la empresa en la cual trabajo, me pidieron hacerlo en en excel y pdf , la cuestion es que al crear el reporte en pdf el encabezado el cual esta formado por el logo, titulo y la fecha se empalma con el contenido con una tabla que es la que se muestra en el reporte ya le e estado moviendo a las posiciones pero no mas no queda ,me podrían ayudar en como solucionar este problema?, les dejo parte del código que uso y la imagen del reporte. saludos.

[image: IMAGEN DEL REPORTE EN PDF]
**Primera parte que uso para generar el PDF**

```
 public ActionResult Download_Rep_Pdf_Administrativo()
    {
        //Guardo en memoria
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        //Indicamos donde vamos a guardar el documento
        string directorioRaiz = "~/App_Data/";
        string NombreArchivoPDF = "C_Administrativa " + DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ".pdf";
        //Indicamos donde esta guardada la imagen
        //string directorioRaiz_Img = "~/Imagenes/";
        //string NombreArchivoImg = "ESCUDO_2019_VERSION_1_Vertical_opt_500X500px.png";


        Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER.Rotate(), 30f, 30f, 60f, 50f);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);
        writer.PageEvent = new HeaderFooter();
        doc.Open();
        Font _standardFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 8, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
        Font _standardFontHeader = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 8, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
        Font _standardFontTotales = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 8, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
        doc.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4.Rotate());//Horizontal
        PdfPTable tablaDetalle = new PdfPTable(8);/*aqui va el numero de registros/Columnas*/
        tablaDetalle.WidthPercentage = 100f;

        doc.AddTitle("Clasificacion Administrativa "+DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
        doc.AddCreator("© " + DateTime.Now.Year + " - Empresa");


        try
        {

            #region Encabzado de tabla
            //Configuramos el título de las columnas de la tabla
            PdfPCell clNum = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("#", _standardFontHeader));
            //clNum.BorderWidth = 0;
            //clNum.BorderWidthBottom = 0.75f;

            PdfPCell clCONCEPTO = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("CONCEPTO", _standardFontHeader));
            //clCONCEPTO.BorderWidth = 0;
            //clCONCEPTO.BorderWidthBottom = 0.75f;

            PdfPCell clAPROBADO = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("APROBADO(1)", _standardFontHeader));
            //clAPROBADO.BorderWidth = 0;
            //clAPROBADO.BorderWidthBottom = 0.75f;

            PdfPCell clAMPLIACIONESRED = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("AMPLIACIONES REDUCCIONES(2)", _standardFontHeader));
            //clAMPLIACIONESRED.BorderWidth = 0;
            //clAMPLIACIONESRED.BorderWidthBottom = 0.75f;

            PdfPCell clMODIFICADO = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("MODIFICADO(3=1+2)", _standardFontHeader));
            //clMODIFICADO.BorderWidth = 0;
            //clMODIFICADO.BorderWidthBottom = 0.75f;

            PdfPCell clDEVENGADO = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("DEVENGADO(4)", _standardFontHeader));
            //clDEVENGADO.BorderWidth = 0;
            //clDEVENGADO.BorderWidthBottom = 0.75f;

            PdfPCell clPAGADO = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("PAGADO(5)", _standardFontHeader));
            //clPAGADO.BorderWidth = 0;
            //clPAGADO.BorderWidthBottom = 0.75f;

            PdfPCell clSUBEJERCIDO = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("SUB EJERCIDO(6=3-4)", _standardFontHeader));
            //clSUBEJERCIDO.BorderWidth = 0;
            //clSUBEJERCIDO.BorderWidthBottom = 0.75f;

            //Añadimos las celdas a la tabla
            tablaDetalle.AddCell(clNum);
            tablaDetalle.AddCell(clCONCEPTO);
            tablaDetalle.AddCell(clAPROBADO);
            tablaDetalle.AddCell(clAMPLIACIONESRED);
            tablaDetalle.AddCell(clMODIFICADO);
            tablaDetalle.AddCell(clDEVENGADO);
            tablaDetalle.AddCell(clPAGADO);
            tablaDetalle.AddCell(clSUBEJERCIDO);
            #endregion

            #region Llenado de la tabla
            var la = TempData["ListaClasificacion"] as List<Administrativo>;

            int contador = 0;
            foreach (Administrativo a in la)
            {
                if (a.Concepto != "TOTAL DEL GASTO")
                {
                    clNum = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(a.Cuenta, _standardFont));
                    //clNum.BorderWidth = 0;

                    clCONCEPTO = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(a.Concepto, _standardFont));
                    //clCONCEPTO.BorderWidth = 0;

                    clAPROBADO = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(a.Aprobado, _standardFont));
                    //clAPROBADO.BorderWidth = 0;

                    clAMPLIACIONESRED = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(a.AmpliaReduc, _standardFont));
                    //clAMPLIACIONESRED.BorderWidth = 0;

                    clMODIFICADO = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(a.Modificado, _standardFont));
                    //clMODIFICADO.BorderWidth = 0;

                    clDEVENGADO = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(a.Devengado, _standardFont));
                    //clDEVENGADO.BorderWidth = 0;

                    clPAGADO = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(a.Pagado, _standardFont));
                    //clPAGADO.BorderWidth = 0;

                    clSUBEJERCIDO = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(a.SubEjercicio, _standardFont));
                    //clSUBEJERCIDO.BorderWidth = 0;

                    // Añadimos las celdas a la tabla
                    // Añadimos las celdas a la tabla
                    tablaDetalle.AddCell(clNum);
                    tablaDetalle.AddCell(clCONCEPTO);
                    tablaDetalle.AddCell(clAPROBADO);
                    tablaDetalle.AddCell(clAMPLIACIONESRED);
                    tablaDetalle.AddCell(clMODIFICADO);
                    tablaDetalle.AddCell(clDEVENGADO);
                    tablaDetalle.AddCell(clPAGADO);
                    tablaDetalle.AddCell(clSUBEJERCIDO);
                    if (contador == 10)
                    {
                        //doc.NewPage();
                        contador = 0;
                    }
                    contador++;
                }
                else
                {
                    clNum = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(a.Cuenta, _standardFontTotales));
                    //clNum.BorderWidth = 0;

                    clCONCEPTO = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(a.Concepto, _standardFontTotales));
                    //clCONCEPTO.BorderWidth = 0;

                    clAPROBADO = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(a.Aprobado, _standardFontTotales));
                    //clAPROBADO.BorderWidth = 0;

                    clAMPLIACIONESRED = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(a.AmpliaReduc, _standardFontTotales));
                    //clAMPLIACIONESRED.BorderWidth = 0;

                    clMODIFICADO = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(a.Modificado, _standardFontTotales));
                    //clMODIFICADO.BorderWidth = 0;

                    clDEVENGADO = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(a.Devengado, _standardFontTotales));
                    //clDEVENGADO.BorderWidth = 0;

                    clPAGADO = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(a.Pagado, _standardFontTotales));
                    //clPAGADO.BorderWidth = 0;

                    clSUBEJERCIDO = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(a.SubEjercicio, _standardFontTotales));
                    //clSUBEJERCIDO.BorderWidth = 0;

                    // Añadimos las celdas a la tabla
                    // Añadimos las celdas a la tabla
                    tablaDetalle.AddCell(clNum);
                    tablaDetalle.AddCell(clCONCEPTO);
                    tablaDetalle.AddCell(clAPROBADO);
                    tablaDetalle.AddCell(clAMPLIACIONESRED);
                    tablaDetalle.AddCell(clMODIFICADO);
                    tablaDetalle.AddCell(clDEVENGADO);
                    tablaDetalle.AddCell(clPAGADO);
                    tablaDetalle.AddCell(clSUBEJERCIDO);
                }
            }
            #endregion

            //Cerramos el documento
            //doc.Add(tablaHeader);
            doc.Add(tablaDetalle);

            doc.Close();
            byte[] bytestream = ms.ToArray();

            ms = new MemoryStream();
            ms.Write(bytestream, 0, bytestream.Length);
            ms.Position = 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Models.Clasificador c = new Models.Clasificador();
            ViewData["DespliegaLista"] = 0;
            ViewData["TipoReporte"] = "0";
            ViewBag.ddl = c.listatipoReporte();
            ViewBag.ddlMes = c.listaMes();
            ViewBag.ddlAnio = c.listaAnio();
            ModelState.AddModelError("Ocurrio Un Error Inesperado", ex.ToString());
        }
        return new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/pdf");
    }
```

**Este es el segundo metodo que uso para añadir el encabezado y pie de pagina**

```
public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            Font _standardFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 8, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
            Font _standardFontFooter = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 7, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
            PdfPCell _cell;

            try
            {
                ////Indicamos donde esta guardada la imagen
                //string directorioRaiz_Img = "~/Imagenes/";
                //string NombreArchivoImg = "ESCUDO_2019_VERSION_1_Vertical_opt_500X500px.png";
                #region test
                Image img_LogoMty = Image.GetInstance(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LOGO_MTY_DOC"].ToString()));
                img_LogoMty.BorderWidth = 0;
                img_LogoMty.Alignment = Image.TEXTWRAP | Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
                float percentage = 0.0f;
                percentage = 49 / img_LogoMty.Width;
                //img_LogoMty.SpacingBefore = 15f;
                //img_LogoMty.IndentationLeft = 9f;
                img_LogoMty.ScalePercent(percentage * 100);

                #endregion
                #region HEADER
                PdfPTable tbHeader = new PdfPTable(3);
                tbHeader.TotalWidth = document.PageSize.Width - document.LeftMargin - document.RightMargin;
                //tbHeader.DefaultCell.Border = 0;

                _cell = new PdfPCell(img_LogoMty/*new Paragraph("INSERTE LOGO", _standardFont)*/);
                _cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
                _cell.Border = 0;
                tbHeader.AddCell(_cell);

                 _cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("############ \n ESTADO ANALITICO DEL EJERCICIO DEL PRESUPUESTO DE EGRESOS \n CLASIFICACION ADMINISTRATIVA \n DEL " +_fi+ " AL "+ _ff + ".", _standardFont));
                _cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                _cell.Border = 0;
                tbHeader.AddCell(_cell);

                _cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), _standardFont));
                _cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
                _cell.Border = 0;
                tbHeader.AddCell(_cell);

                tbHeader.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, document.LeftMargin, writer.PageSize.GetTop(document.TopMargin) + 30, writer.DirectContent);
                #endregion

                #region FOOTER
                PdfPTable tbFooter = new PdfPTable(3);
                tbFooter.TotalWidth = document.PageSize.Width - document.LeftMargin - document.RightMargin;
                //tbFooter.DefaultCell.Border = 0;

                tbFooter.AddCell(new Paragraph());

                _cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("© " + DateTime.Now.Year + " - Municipio de Monterrey", _standardFontFooter));
                _cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                _cell.Border = 0;
                tbFooter.AddCell(_cell);

                _cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Pag. " + writer.PageNumber, _standardFontFooter));
                _cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
                _cell.Border = 0;
                tbFooter.AddCell(_cell);

                tbFooter.AddCell(new Paragraph());
                tbFooter.AddCell(_cell);

                tbFooter.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, document.LeftMargin, writer.PageSize.GetBottom(document.BottomMargin) - 5, writer.DirectContent);
                #endregion
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

yo tengo el encabezado de esta forma y no se empalma con mi tabla

```
PdfContentByte cbencabezado = new PdfContentByte(writer);
base.OnStartPage(writer, document);
cbencabezado = writer.DirectContent;
cbencabezado.BeginText();
cbEncabezado.SetFontAndSize(FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, 
iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD).BaseFont, 8);
cbEncabezado.SetCMYKColorFill(0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80);
cbEncabezado.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, "Fichaxxxx", 290, 750, 0);
cbEncabezado.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, "Drxxxxx", 290, 735, 0);
cbEncabezado.EndText();
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// LOGO del encabezado
```

//------------------------------------------------------------------

```
iTextSharp.text.Image logo = 
iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(@"C:\XXXXX\logo.png");
logo.SetAbsolutePosition(35, 717);
logo.ScalePercent(20);
document.Add(logo);
```